# c#.Net: Execute two SQL statements at a time

Tags: c#, sql-server, select

I am wondering if there is any way to execute multiple SQL statements. Like I want to get count as well as the value. How can I do this in c#?

Query 1:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from tblStock where prodName=@prodName", con); // to get count
```

Query 2:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select quantity from tblStock where prodName=@prodName", con);// to get qty

int count, qty;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //returns null if doesnt exist
            qty = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: why not execute them one by one ?

Comment: Isn't there any optimized code to achieve this?

Comment: Is this the bottleneck in your application?  If not, it is unwise to be complicating the code to optimize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't make sense.

If there is more than one row per prodName in tblStock, then what good is returning "quantity" which is not a scalar, but an array of values?

If there is only one row per prodName in tblStock, then what good is asking for a count(*) which is always 1?

Either you want an aggregate value of quantity ("sum(quantity)", perhaps) or you don't need count(*) because there is only one row.

I'm assuming it's the former in which case your SQL query is

```
select sum(quantity) as sumQty, count(*) as ct from tblStock where prodname = @prodName
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you not just select both values in the one select query?

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select quantity, count(*) from tblStock where prodName=@prodName", con);
```

Comment: and then how can i save the result in two different variables? `qty` and `count`?

Comment: You need to use an `SqlDataReader` via `ExecuteReader`.  See here for example usage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx

Comment: Also see here where you can see indexing used to get the column values: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx

Comment: This query will fail since you're not grouping by quantity.

Comment: My point was more to write one query that gets both values at once, rather than to execute two.  The OP can make the query do what's correct, given then know the schema.

Comment: Fair enough, just kinda mean to pass someone code that doesn't work. Maybe pseudocode next time?

Answer (score 0):

you can use SqlDataReader
use statement

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(select sum(quantity) QTY, count(*) from tblStock where prodName=@prodName);

SqlDataReader dr =cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

var Q=dr[0];
var C=dr[1];
```